# Start Minecraft On Mac With Java

Tags: java, macos, minecraft, offline-mode

I am trying to make a java program that will launch minecraft in offline mode with whatever username i want so i can have usernames like Notch and deadmau5 and i am using this code to launch it on mac and windows (Currently Testing on mac):

```
public void startMacMinecraft(String username) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(defaultDirectory());

    String sysUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String commandString = "java -cp "
            + defaultDirectory()
            + "/minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar:"
            + defaultDirectory()
            + "/minecraft/bin/lwjgl.jar:"
            + defaultDirectory()
            + "/minecraft/bin/lwjgl_util.jar:"
            + defaultDirectory()
            + "/minecraft/bin/jinput.jar: -Djava.library.path="
            + defaultDirectory()
            + "/minecraft/bin/natives -Xmx1024M -Xms512M net.minecraft.client.Minecraft '"
            + username + "'";
    CommandLine command = CommandLine.parse(commandString);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    int exitValue = executor.execute(command);
    System.out.println(exitValue);

    System.out.println("\nTry Two:\n");
    String javaExe = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java";

}

public void startWinMinecraft(String username) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    String sysUser = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String commandString = "Java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp \"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\*\" -Djava.library.path=\"%APPDATA%\\.minecraft\\bin\\natives net.minecraft.client.Minecraft \""
            + username + "\"";
    CommandLine command = CommandLine.parse(commandString);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    int exitValue = executor.execute(command);
    System.out.println(exitValue);

}

private static String defaultDirectory() {
    String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toUpperCase();
    if (OS.contains("WIN"))
        return System.getenv("APPDATA");
    else if (OS.contains("MAC"))
        return System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application "
                + "Support";
    else if (OS.contains("NUX"))
        return System.getProperty("user.home");
    return System.getProperty("user.dir");
}
```

Which i am trying to adapt from this applescript which i have run before and got from https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46608/how-can-i-run-minecraft-in-offline-mode-on-os-x-and-still-have-my-name that i will paste right here:

```
property user_name : "Player"

display dialog "Enter A User Name" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2
set the user_name to text returned of the result

set UsrApp to (path to current user folder)
set UsrApp_unx to POSIX path of UsrApp

set MineScript to "java -cp " & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl_util.jar:" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/jinput.jar: -Djava.library.path=" & UsrApp_unx & "Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/natives -Xmx1024M -Xms512M net.minecraft.client.Minecraft '" & user_name & "'"

do shell script MineScript
```

When i run the applescript it works perfectly fine but when i run my adapted version it gives me a class not found error:

```
    Logging in as: Player
/Users/Connor/Library/Application Support
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Support/minecraft/bin/minecraft/jar:/Users/Connor/Library/Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Support.minecraft.bin.minecraft.jar:.Users.Connor.Library.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
    at info.connorbp.GUIApp.LoginPanel.startMacMinecraft(LoginPanel.java:137)
    at info.connorbp.GUIApp.LoginPanel$1.actionPerformed(LoginPanel.java:82)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6375)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6140)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:657)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:655)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:654)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong or how to fix it?

EDIT:

Even stranger yet, I went into the events area of the applescript area and found the exact command the applescript was running:

```
java -cp /Users/Connor/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar:/Users/Connor/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl.jar:/Users/Connor/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/lwjgl_util.jar:/Users/Connor/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/jinput.jar: -Djava.library.path=/Users/Connor/Library/Application\\ Support/minecraft/bin/natives -Xmx1024M -Xms512M net.minecraft.client.Minecraft 'username'
```

and even when a tried running the script that came directly from the applescript i got another java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error, even though i took the command directly from the applescript that is working.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see that there were 2 separate methods.

Comment: Yea, i am trying to make it multi platform. I am adding linux when this current problem is fixed

Comment: it might be useful to edit your question to show a link to the applescript that *does* work, so perhaps this questions' readers can figure out what the difference is between your busted script and the one that works.

Comment: I did put a link to the applescript that works. -.- There is no non working applescript. The applescript works, but the java code does not work and the consol command doesn't work. Why is no one actually reading my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, forgot about this question. I was actually just missing some of the code that was needed in order to launch minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

In the default launcher, whatever username you provide gets used for offline mode, so writing a separate launcher is pointless.

In any case, decompiling the launcher should give us a pretty good idea of how to launch the game.

There is a lot of code so I recommend decompiling it yourself. For mac, JD-GUI does an alright job. For windows, I can't recommend a decompiler, but thats what google is for :)

After you get the launcher source code, have a peek at `public void login(String userName, String password)` in net.minecraft.LauncherFrame. Also relevant is net.minecraft.Launcher.

Reading through that should give you a pretty good idea of how to launch minecraft.